# How to create multiple .vimrc for several languages?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am learning Vim and quickly discovering how awesome it is. I have my .vimrc set up for python but now I want to fully integrate my life with vim. So how can I create a separate .vimrc for each language? 
I have downloaded emmet for html and put this in my .vim and I am unable to use emmet right now either.

I have tried ~/.vim/ftplugin/java.vim but i was unable to create the new .vim file

I do have emmet I just do not know how to get it to work. http://mattn.github.io/emmet-vim/  Is the best i things I have found

Comment: using a plugin manager makes things far more easier, I personally use pathogen, and installing new plugins becomes as easy as cloning a git repo. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in using different settings, keymappings, etc. you can achieve this in a single .vimrc by making use of `autocmd`. (Your language specific plugins *should* handle this on their own. e.g. Python plugins would only take effect when editing Python files.)

From [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html):

> You can specify commands to be executed automatically when reading or writing
>   a file, when entering or leaving a buffer or window, and when exiting Vim.

For instance, here's a section of my .vimrc:

```
" set shiftwidth and softtabstops to 2 when working with Clojure, Ruby, HAML, etc.
autocmd FileType clojure,ruby,haml,eruby,yaml,cucumber set ai sw=2 sts=2 et

" map ctrl-e to vim-fireplace's Eval function when working with Clojure files
autocmd FileType clojure nnoremap <C-e> :Eval<CR>
```

Comment: That's what `ftplugin` files are for (cf. `:h ftplugin`).

Answer (score 3):

Vim has the notion of *filetype plugins*. You enable them via `:filetype plugin on` (in your `~/.vimrc`). Then, whenever you edit a Python / Java / whatever file, Vim will load corresponding settings for that particular programming language. You can adapt / override / extend those settings with your own, and add (buffer-local) mappings and commands if you like. Read more at `:help ftplugin`.

Therefore, I would recommend putting the settings and mappings into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`, as suggested by @pdoherty926's answer. That's the right mechanism, and it doesn't clutter your `~/.vimrc` with language-specific stuff.